# Cut or replace html tags from text inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form validation. If the user writes html, php, or javascript tags in the inputs, how can i cut or replace them?

Can someone give me a function for that?

```
var ArErros = [];
            var ar_nev, ar_email, ar_tel, ar_uzenet, ar_termek_id;
            ar_nev = $('#ar_nev').val();
            ar_email = $('#ar_email').val();
            ar_tel = $('#ar_tel').val();
            ar_uzenet = $('#ar_uzenet').val();
            ar_termek_id = $('#JobbArItemID').val();

            if($.trim(ar_nev) == "") { ArErros.push("Nem adta meg a nevét."); }
            if($.trim(ar_email) == "") { ArErros.push("Nem adta meg az e-mail címét."); }
            if(ar_email != "")
            {
                if(validate_Email(ar_email) == false)
                {
                    ArErros.push("Elképzelhető, hogy hibásan adta meg az e-mail címét.");
                }
            }
            if($.trim(ar_tel) == "") { ArErros.push("Nem adta meg a telefonszámát."); }
            if($.trim(ar_uzenet) == "") { ArErros.push("Nem írt semmilyen kérdést vagy üzenetet."); }
            if($.trim(ar_termek_id) == "") { ArErros.push("Hiányzik a termék ID."); }
            if(ar_termek_id != "")
            {
                if(!$.isNumeric(ar_termek_id))
                {
                    ArErros.push("A termék ID nem szám típusú.");
                }
            }
```

Comment: there's no php in there

Comment: Don't. Just store and render the input as text. They'll quickly learn that typing `<marquee>I Da Bomb!</marquee>` just makes `<marquee>I Da Bomb!</marquee>` (not a marquee) show up. After all, users should be able to write things like "I'm fairly sure 1 < 10", right? Or "Anyone know where I should put my <script> tags?" (E.g., do what SO is doing with what I'm typing here.)

Comment: I corrected, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read through this [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](http://XSS%20prevention%20cheat%20sheet) to learn the dangers you will need to look into, especially the Prevention rules Summary section which shows where dangerous code could be loaded. For a very basic implementation you could use replace to escape entities from a form field:

```
var escaped = text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                      .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                      .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                      .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                      .replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser's inbuilt code to do this like below.

```
function StripHTML(strhtml)
{
   var tmpDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmpDiv.innerHTML = strhtml;
   return tmpDiv.textContent || tmpDiv.innerText || "";
}
```